# Using numpy.min to get minimum value in a float64 type numpy array but got error 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to get the minimum value between tr_loss and val_loss using `numpy.min`.

```
np.min(np.min(tr_loss), np.min(val_loss))
```

The tr_loss and val_loss are numpy arrays that returned from `model.fit` in keras.

```
'tr_loss': [0.84579472304284575, 0.77913203762769701, 0.76625978895127778, 0.75814685845822094, 0.75486504282504319, 0.74989902700781819, 0.74833822523653504, 0.74695981823652979, 0.74483485338091848, 0.74150521695762872]

'val_loss': [0.76307238261103627, 0.75163262798049202, 0.74257619685517573, 0.75038179922993964, 0.72936564083517463, 0.73233943380595634, 0.72518632964207708, 0.74037907492741795, 0.7237680551772061, 0.73257833277079065]}
```

But I keep getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-e82cb24a3b5d> in <module>()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 y_ax_min = np.min(np.min(tr_loss), np.min(val_loss)) - .1
      6 y_ax_max = np.max(np.max(tr_loss), np.max(val_loss)) + .1
      7 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8),dpi=500)

D:\Anaconda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in 
amin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
   2347             pass
   2348         else:
-> 2349             return amin(axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
   2350 
   2351     return _methods._amin(a, axis=axis,

D:\Anaconda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.pyc in _amin(a, 
axis, out, keepdims)
     27 
     28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 29     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Start by reading `help(numpy.min)`. You aren't calling it as intended. The second argument should be an axis. It's not like the built in `min` function.

Comment: When comparing two elements, `numpy.minimum` should be used instead of `numpy.min`. @ChrisP Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing two elements, [`numpy.minimum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) should be used instead of [`numpy.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html).

The comments on this question helped me. Thanks to all those who commented.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).